# Redhat 6.8 - Where to install php-mssql

Tags: linux, centos, php, sql-server, redhat

I tried following tons resources online to install php-mssql on Redhat 6.8 by using the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repo and it says that "No package php-mssql available". I made sure to enable the EPEL as well with no success (maybe php-mssql isn't in EPEL anymore?). I did end up installing freetds from EPEL though.

Can someone guide me in the right direction on installing php-mssql package?

Update:

```
# yum install epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
# yum-config-manager --enable epel
# yum install php-mssql
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-
: manager
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mssql available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

From the request of John:

```
# vim /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1


# ls
epel.repo  epel-testing.repo  redhat.repo  rhel-source.repo

# yum search php-mssql
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager
No Matches found

# yum search php | grep mssql
[nothing found]
```

Comment: It actually is in EPEL. You will need to post the complete output from your commands.

Comment: I updated what I did and it seems like php-mssql isn't in there. I also enabled everything with "epel*" in it and it still says that the package is not available.

Comment: Is your RHEL subscription active? You can't install packages if you do not have a subscription or it has expired.

Comment: It's active. I did: # subscription-manager register --username [insert_name] --password [insert_password] --auto-attach.

Comment: rpmfind.net lists it in epel6:  http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/epel/6/x86_64/php-mssql-5.3.3-4.el6.x86_64.html

Comment: If it's in epel6, how come I'm able to install freetds but not php-mssql?

Comment: Can you post the content from your epel config files /etc/yum-repos.d/ also search the Php packages and make sure you're referencing the package correctly : yum search php | grep mssql

Comment: I added what you requested John.